# How can we to add a td into tr tag for a zend_form?

Tags: php, zend-form

I am wondering long time.I am not getting proper way for zend_form. How can we to add a td into tr tag in a zend_form? so how can we solve this problem in zend framework. any one help me please.
 its look like below code:

```
<table>
      <tr>
       <td><input type='checkbox' id='something'/></td>
       <td><img src='src'/></td>
       <td><input type='text' id='something'/></td>
       <td><input type='radio' group='justonegroup'/></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

My code is like :

```
          $pollAdd->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',
            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
            array(array('emptyrow' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td',                 )),
array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag') , array('tag' => 'tr','id'=>'trRowAdd')))); 


    $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag' , array('tag' => 'table' , 'class' =>'formTable')),
            'Form'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Send Form [setDecorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html)

Something like ,

```
   $this->setElementDecorators(array(
                'viewHelper',
                'Errors',
                array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td')),
                array('Label',array('tag'=>'td')),
                array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))

    ),array('firstname','lastname'));
```

Form itself will have the `table` html tag like below,

```
 $form->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table')),
    'Form',
  ));
```

Comment: But output is only like this: <tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='something'/></td><td><img src='src'/></td></tr> I want to make four td tag into tr tag. So I used above code but its not working. how can solve?

Comment: It is not working properly Rakesh. its made only two td into tr tag. Please. I want to make 4 td in tr tag.

Comment: You have to use this decorator for all of your four element...this will helps you how -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507700/zend-form-decorators-causing-me-headache